# Need to run powershell script asynchronously on remote when a request hits webapi

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-web-api, powershell-remoting

I am using `System.Management.Automation` assembly for this

```bash
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
                try
                {
                  runspace.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Error("Unable to connect to remote machine" + ex.Message);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to remote machine");
                }
              
                    Pipeline pipeline;
                    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ps.Runspace = runspace;
                            pipeline = ps.Runspace.CreatePipeline();
                            Command command = new       Command(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScriptPath"].ToString());
                            command.Parameters.Add("inputobj", ConvertModeltoPsobject(obj));   
                            pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
                            pipeline.Input.Close();
                            pipeline.InvokeAsync();
                             while (pipeline.PipelineStateInfo.State != PipelineState.Running)
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(100);
                        }}
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            //problem running script
                            Logger.Error(e.Message);
                        }
                       
                    }
                runspace.Close();
```

This is working when single request hits the api but when multiple requests hit its only processing the first one.

The powershell script on the remote copy files from that server other server.that's why it is taking time and we are checking the condition pipeline.PipelineStateInfo.State != PipelineState.Running

I have tried creating RunspacePool but facing an error that method is not supported.
RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool(minRunspaces, maxRunspaces, connectionInfo)

Is there any reason why RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool(minRunspaces, maxRunspaces, connectionInfo) is not supporting.

Comment: Please post your error message(s) in full